# Minimal value in real numbers $p,q,r,s$ with constraints

Tags: inequality, optimization

**Original question**

Real numbers $p,q,r,s$ lie in $\color{#c00}{[1,2]}$ and satisfy $(p+r)(q+s)=8$. Prove that $pqrs≥4$.

---

**Edited question**

Real numbers $p,q,r,s$ lie in $[1,2]$ and satisfy $(p+r)(q+s)=8$. Prove that $pqrs≤4$.

---

I've tried using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality; we have
\begin{align*}
(p+q+r+s)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{s}\right)\leq 16\text{,}
\end{align*}
although further manipulation doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Another approach uses AM-GM; indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
p+q+r+s\geq 4\sqrt[4]{pqrs}
\text{,}
\end{align*}
which doesn't seem helpful either. The solution shouldn't require higher mathematics.

Comment: Edit the question and add your approach inspite of your failure.

Comment: Are you sure that the desired conclusion is not $pqrs \le 4$ ?

Comment: Please, do not change the question after receiving answer . Now, my answer is invalid .

Comment: @lonestudent: If a statement is so obviously wrong then I would recommend to ask for clarification before writing an answer.

Comment: @MartinR I agree, but in general after receiving the answer, non-trivial edit is not true .

Comment: @lonestudent In my opinion, in this case, we may write a comment rather than an answer in a rush, because perhaps some typos exist. I recently found [an example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452948/an-inequality-for-a-concave-function-fx-xp-2). In my opinion, the answer there is not necessary which should be a comment.

Comment: @RiverLi Here the range $[1,2]$ is given and I gave a counterexample that fits this range. The point is, when I answered, the question already had answers.  That's why I gave the next answer. But, yes I would definitely leave the first answer as a comment .

Comment: @lonestudent Thanks. I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of [Martin R's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r) hint, we have

\begin{align*}
(p+r)(q+s)&=8\\
\frac{(p+r)(q+s)}{4}&=2\\
\frac{p+r}{2}\cdot \frac{q+s}{2}&=2\text{,}
\end{align*}
but by AM-GM we have
\begin{align*}
2=\frac{p+r}{2}\cdot \frac{q+s}{2}\geq \sqrt{pr}\cdot \sqrt{qs}
\end{align*}
and squaring gives the desired result $4\geq pqrs$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to minimize $pqrs$ subject to $(p+r)(q+s) = 8$, with $1 \le p,q,r,s \le 2$.
Note that for given $q$ and $s$, $p+r = 8/(q+s)$ is fixed, and the minimum is attained when $p=r = 4/(q+s)$ (which of course must be in the interval $[1,2]$).
So...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for any $\,p,q,r,s\in\Bbb R^+,\,$ it results that

$(p+r)(q+s)=8\;$ implies $\;pqrs\leqslant4\,.$

**Proof:**
$\begin{align}pqrs&=\dfrac1{16}\big(4pr\big)\!\cdot\!\big(4qs\big)\leqslant\\[3pt]&\leqslant\dfrac1{16}\big[4pr+(p-r)^2\big]\big[4qs+(q-s)^2\big]=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1{16}\big(p+r\big)^2\!\!\cdot\!\big(q+s\big)^2\!=\dfrac1{16}\big[(p+r)(q+s)\big]^2\!=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1{16}\!\cdot\!8^2=4\,.\end{align}$